# Matplotlib & Dynamic Web Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, matplotlib

I have been using WxPython, Matplotlib, Numpy, Scipy quiet a time and familiar with developing Web Page.

Is it possible that using WxPython, Matplotlib I can create or render a dynamic web page via Apapche - WxPython has its own output window which I do not want to make use.

My aim is to create a dynamic web page using JS / Jquery where users can enter values in text boxes, select via drop down list etc (all HTML UI items) - then a plot is rendered in the same web page. The user over and over again selects or modifies the values and the graph gets modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For providing a web service you will probably want to reorganize your application code such that you can share the matplotlib things between a wxPython application and a separate web services application.  (So, IOW, move the non wx application code to a separate set of packages that can be shared with your new web application code, for example.)

Once that is done then can do things like have your new web application use the shared code, have matplotlib generate plots as PNG files and serve those PNGs to the browser. Etc.